# html comment delimiters stripped in preg_match result

Tags: php, regex

I have this php code which extracts content of html comments. (I know it will not work with comments that are not continuous strings but that's ok).

```
preg_match_all('<!--\*\*(\w+)\*\*-->', $content, $matches)
```

This returns

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => !--**navigation**-- [1] => !--**form**-- [2] => !--**footer**-- ) 
  [1] => Array ( [0] => navigation          [1] => form          [2] => footer ) )
```

This is fine, except that that "<" and ">" characters have been stripped from the match in the first sub-array. Any way to retain them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not using regex delimiters, use:

```
preg_match_all('~<!--\*\*(\w+)\*\*-->~', $content, $matches);
```

**Or better use `s` (DOTALL) flag with `.*?` to match multiline comments as well:**

```
preg_match_all('~<!--\*\*(.*?)\*\*-->~s', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: The amount of content typed matters too :P

Comment: lol :) didn't realize this question got so much attention in India :)

Comment: *+1*. I just went ahead and deleted my answer. This one's definitely better with the addition of DOTALL modifier :)

Comment: i wondered that all the three answers uses the same delimiter `~` . I also deleted....

Comment: Using the tilde delimiter returns empty values in the first match array, i.e.:

Comment: @AvinashRaj you typed all those on mobile?salute :P

Comment: Thanks for posting code. Yes, the match definitely works, I get the content of the comment, but the actual comment strings in the first  array are empty, for some reason It's not a huge problem, I can enclose with <, > delimiters programatically. Thanks for effort all.

Comment: OK, final comment: silly mistake on my part. Echoed the matches to a browser. The browser of course interpreted anything enclosed in </> as a tag and did not display it. So using tildes of course works fine.